# Lambda calculus entire expression substitution

Tags: lambda-calculus

About substitution of free occurances: can we have a substitution of an entire expression(function, application), or just of a variable:

Example:

- Current expression \x.\y.(y, z)
- Expression to be replaced: \y.(y z) with p so we will have \x.p.

Is it possible?

Comment: What is a free occurrence of an expression?

Comment: I was talking about an expression seen as a variable. Thus a free occurance of an expression means the same thing as a free occurance of a variable if you replace the expression with a variable. That was my question, howeverI think it is not possible. Also I don't see why it is a bad question.

Comment: There are several equivalent formal definitions of "free occurrence of a variable."  All you have to do is rewrite those definitions, replacing "variable" with "expression" appropriately and see if any of them make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. One way is to consider the substitution of occurrences. An occurrence is a string over the set `{1,2,3}`, and for every lambda-term `M`, the sub-expression `M/u` at occurrence `u` is defined as:

- `M/[]` = `M`
- `M/0u` = `N/u`, if `M=\x. N`
- `M/1u` = `P/u`, if `M=PQ`
- `M/2u` = `Q/u`, if `M=PQ`

(I use the symbol `[]` to denote the empty string.)

Now define the substitution `M[u := N]` as the term obtained from replacing the occurrence `u` with `N` in `M`. I've seen this kind of substitution in some of P.-L. Curien work.